# Tailwind not working when using variables (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-props, default-parameters

currently have been facing this issue using tailwind and making rehusable react components where you can pass as a prop some styles as tailwind classes. The actual problem is with the "pb-{number}" propierty. I can pass it this way and will work fine. This also happens with "border-{number}" property, but someway it accepts border-2 and border-4 (only these).

```
import './button.css'
    
    export default function Button({
        color = "orange",
        inset = "pb-3", <--- this will work
        border = "border-8",
        className, 
        onClick, 
        link
        , ...props}){
        
        return (
            <div onClick={onClick}
            className={`btn-${color} ${border} 
            ${className} ${inset}`}> <--- this will work
                
                <div>
                    {props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
```

But if I try to make it cleaner so a person who don't use tailwind only has to pass a value (like the example below) it wont work.

```
import './button.css'

export default function Button({
    color = "orange",
    inset = "1", <--- this
    border = "4",
    className, 
    onClick, 
    link
    , ...props}){
    
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}
        className={`btn-${color} border-${border} 
        ${className} pb-${inset}`}> <--- this wont work
            
            <div>
                {props.children}
            </div>                

        </div>
    )
}
```

Sincerely I have no idea why is this happening. Hope someone with more experience can clarify my doubt.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, as the Tailwind docs state clearly this will not work https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names your classes will be purged.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to avoid general classes like in this case eg: padding, border,.... to be purged? Btw, thanks, didnt get why some composed classes were working while others don't, so if I get it right all the classes that have been used at least 1 time wont be purged? or it needs to be used at least one time within the component?

Comment: Sure, you can safelist classes https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes. You could even write a regex to define a long list of classes to safelist from purging. However, if this is a user-facing application or site it's better to avoid this behavior, it can cause some very large output files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In tailwind you can't use dynamic class naming like bg-${color}, though we can mock it to be that, but it is not preferred. Because Tailwind compiles its CSS,  it looks up over all of your code and checks if a class name matches.

For your approach you can try this.

```
const Button = () => {
  const color = "red-500";
  const inset = "3";
  const border = "border-8";
  return <div className={`bg-${color}  ${border} pb-${inset}`}>Hello</div>;
};

export default Button;
```

Output with proper `padding` is applied
[image]

But try avoiding this workaround, as it is not recommended by the Tailwind CSS.